# Why is video playing in Firefox but not in Chrome or Safari?

Tags: video.js

I have a video thumbnail on the top right of this screen that, when clicked, plays fine in Firefox. However, in Chrome and Safari the video will not play. The loading image spins forever and will not continue to the video.

Any advice is much appreciated. I have tried upgrading VideoJS from v2.0.2 to v4.1.0 and that still did not solve the problem.

Here is the link: http://www.therefinerycreative.com/#!/theatrical

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is the actual source movie files that are the problem. The mp4 file is 15mb which is quite big for a 1 minute movie. I can see the dimension size of the movie is fine. Try decreasing the size of the file down first. Or to save you time first, try putting in the standard video from videojs just to double check that it definitely is the source file(s). http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4

I also noticed that you use an ogg file too. In most cases you can get away with just using an mp4 file. Try both of these solutions and let me know how you get on.